# Dokan: Should I handle file sharing and access rights myself

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, driver, dokan

I am trying to create a file system driver with Dokan. But now I got confused about if I should handle the complex stuff myself.

Some examples:

- Two consecutive calls to `CreateFile()` with sharing mode set to `0`.
- Delete a opened file(without `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` set).
- Request `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` access when the file has been opened with `FIlE_SHARE_READ`.

In these conditions, Windows will obviously return an error. But I'm not sure it will be automatically handled by the Windows kernel or is the duty of my file system application.

Comment: all this tasks is done by filesystem driver. windows kernel (I/O subsystem) not handle this.

Comment: @RbMm Thank you for your information. Would you like to post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote  please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when kernel handle create/open file request (say [`IoCreateFile\[Ex\]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548418(v=vs.85).aspx)) it check only that `ShareAccess` have valid mask:

`if (ShareAccess & ~FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS) return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;`

and store `ShareAccess` in `IO_STACK_LOCATION.Parameters.Create.ShareAccess` then already FS driver task use/check it. however usually FS drivers use system supplied [`IoCheckShareAccess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548341(v=vs.85).aspx) routine for this (look for example [`FatCheckShareAccess`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L6822))

for delete file - we open file with option `FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`. kernel only check that in this case we request `DELETE` in `DesiredAccess`

`if ((CreateOptions & FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE) && !(DesiredAccess & DELETE)) return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;`

but main task handle this is FS responsibility - search for [`DeleteOnClose`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L754) in [`create.c`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c)

> Request `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` access when the file has been opened with
>   `FIlE_SHARE_READ`

this check exactly done in [`IoCheckShareAccess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548341(v=vs.85).aspx) (look for it code in [`iosubs.c`](http://gate.upm.ro/os/LABs/Windows_OS_Internals_Curriculum_Resource_Kit-ACADEMIC/WindowsResearchKernel-WRK/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/io/iomgr/iosubs.c) ) but `FS` must direct call this routine with `IrpSp->Parameters.Create.ShareAccess`